# Programmatically start div and issue with closing the same div, Encountered end tag "div" with no matching start tag.

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to generate following html

```
<div id="my-grid" class="isotope">
   <div class="myProject-item">....</div>
   <div class="myProject-item">....</div>
   <div class="myProject-item">....</div>
   <div class="myProject-item">....</div>
</div>
```

basically every 4th row (I have more than 200 rows) (div with class myProject-item) should be wrapperd inside  `<div id="my-grid" class="isotope">`

so I tried following

```
@{
    var counter = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < 200; i++)
    {
        counter++;
        if (counter % 4 == 0)
        {
          <text><div id="my-grid" class="isotope"></text>
        }
         <div class="myProject-item">....</div>
        if (counter % 4 == 0)
        {
           </div> // ***** on this line render breaks ******    
        }      
    }
}
```

> Parser Error Message: Encountered end tag "div" with no matching start
>   tag.  Are your start/end tags properly balanced?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, You must have missed that OP is using razor. Where anything inside `<text></text>` is treated as content block

Comment: @Satpal yep, you're right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify that closing `</div>` is a content block.

```
        if (counter % 4 == 0)
        {
           <text></div> </text>
        }
```

Alternatively `@:` sequence can also be used, it will indicates that the line of content that follows should be treated as a content block.

```
@{
    var counter = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < 200; i++)
    {
        counter++;
        if (counter % 4 == 0)
        {
          @:<div id="my-grid" class="isotope">
        }
         <div class="myProject-item">....</div>
        if (counter % 4 == 0)
        {
           @:</div> 
        }      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your opening `<div>` is inside your `<text></text>`. Move it outside and it should work.